Delete repeated adjacent characters from the string in snowflake?
I have a string: 'ABC/DEF-GHI/GHI/IJK-LMN/GHI'
I want to delete the repeated occurrence of GHI followed by DEF-GHI, but not delete the last GHI because it is not adjacent to another GHI.
Expected output: 'ABC/DEF-GHI/IJK-LMN/GHI'
I would like to achieve this using REGEX expressions.
I tried this and adjusted this many ways but I'm still not seeing the expected output, I'm new to both regex and snowflake.
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC/DEF-GHI/GHI/IJK-LMN/GHI', '([A-Za-z]{3})(\/)\1', '\\1') AS cleaned_text;

TIA.

What if you use SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC/DEF-GHI/GHI/IJK-LMN/GHI', '([A-Za-z]{3})\\/\1', '\\1') AS cleaned_text;

back references are not supported in the matching side.

I would create a user defined javascript function, and use the full regex engine of that layer, to do the lifting.

I ended up using UDF in Javascript as Simeon suggested, did not use Regex but just a small function to handle the case.
